# How to set keyboard layout at machine level in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-layout

I have 2 laptops running Windows 8 and I am using my Microsoft Account between them.

Trouble is, one laptop has a UK keyboard and the other a US keyboard.

So far it seems that the keyboard layout is now attached to my profile and not the machine, which is a problem.
I sit down at the UK keyboard and the layout is set to US. I keep typing " instead of @ and vice-versa.
So I change it over to UK layout and all is well.
Later I open up the US keyboard and its got a UK layout and I'm typing @ instead of " again.

So- Does anyone know of a way to force a keyboard layout to be machine-specific when using Microsoft accounts?

Comment: Have you tried telling Windows not to sync this particular setting?

Comment: This is particularly maddening when the layout switched from QWERTY to dvorak mid-sentence...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This drove me crazy too.  I think I've figured it out.

1. Go to the charms area (slam into the right-top/bottom corner)
2. Click on the settings cog
3. Click on "Change PC settings"
4. Click on "Sync your settings"
5. Switch "Language preferences" to "Off"

Pain reduced.